# wireless problem ubuntu 12.04, rfkill commands not working and no internet access via cable

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

I am new to ubuntu and I needed it for some college software. After hours of trying, destroying windows, recovering windows etc. i managed to install ubuntu 12.04. The problem is that on my HP dv6 the wifi switch has the red light on as not working and the only options i find on the wireless applet are:

VPN Connections
Enable networking (with a check)
Edit connections...

None of the rfkill commands seem to do anything at all, they don't even list anything.
I don't have a wired access to the internet so I was wondering if i could fix the issue in another way

Thanks in advance

Comment: Click on the applet for the networking: Does it say something like "Networking disabled" or anything?

Comment: Check this site for some tips on trouble shooting wireless connnections :
[wifi docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, fixed it by using my android phone as an internet source through an usb cable and then updating the system by just hitting ok to the automatic updates that show up on screen